# Get additional metrics in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, metrics

in Visual Studio 2019 these six metrics are available:
Maintainability Index, Cyclomatic complexity, Depth of Inheritance, Class Coupling, Lines of Source Code and Lines of Executable Code (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-metrics-values?view=vs-2019)

The question is:
Are there any extensions that offer more metrics than these six? I already tried to find some with Google but did not find anything.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The Visual Studio extensions NDepend for .NET code and CppDepend for C++ code propose many more code metrics, see the list [here](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics).

The tools propose to [query these code metrics](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features#Metrics) with C# LINQ query which leads to some [rules](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1000#!) (for example *warn for methods whose cyclomatic complexity is higher than 20*)

With these tools the code metrics [can be visualized with colored treemap](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/treemap-visualization-of-code-metrics), here for example we see *lines of code* (rectangle area) vs. *code coverage* (red to green color)

[image: Visual Studio Code Metric Treemap]

Comment: Nice thing! Is there a possibility to get it for free as a student?

Comment: please come back to us per email and we'll discuss, support at ndepend dot com